# I am having trouble in my javascript code where a part of the code doesn't see an object that was previously defined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I created this container called `vacationMembers` to hold some names.

```
vacationMembers = {};

vacationMembers["Zie"] = true;
vacationMembers["Timoty"] = true;
vacationMembers["Risha"] = true;
vacationMembers["Germaine"] = true;
```

Now I want to check to see if a particular person is in that group like this:

```
export function isVacationMember(familyMember) {
    if (vacationMembers[familyMember.name]) { 
        return true;
    };
    return false;
}
```

But when I run it, I get this error:

```
ReferenceError: vacationMembers is not defined
```

I checked the spelling and everything seems fine.

Is there anything else I need to check?

Thanks!

Comment: Surely `vacationMembers` should be explicitly declared with `let` or `const` or `var`. However, even then, what you posted does not include enough detail to say what the problem is.

Comment: @Pointy honestly it's just a JavaScript file that uses `export` for a bunch of functions.  The only thing I didn't include was the other function definitions (which do work fine).

Comment: Well that's fine, but if you're getting this anomalous "not defined" error then there is clearly **something** about your code that's wrong. You did not post enough to show what the problem is.

Comment: @Pointy thanks! You fixed it!  Simply adding a `let` before `vacationMembers` like this: `let vacationMembers = {};`   Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error "ReferenceError: vacationMembers is not defined" typically occurs when trying to access a variable or object that hasn't been defined within the current scope. In your case, it seems that the `vacationMembers` object is defined in one module but not accessible in the module where the `isVacationMember` function is defined.

Here's how you can do it:

**Define vacationMembers in a module and export it:**

```
// vacationMembersModule.js

export const vacationMembers = {
    "Zie": true,
    "Timoty": true,
    "Risha": true,
    "Germaine": true
};

import { vacationMembers } from './path/to/vacationMembersModule.js';

export function isVacationMember(familyMember) {
    if (vacationMembers[familyMember.name]) { 
        return true;
    };
    return false;
}
```